# How can I open a socket on a specific url?

Tags: c++

NOTE: I do not know c++ very well.
I am using a site hosting (000webhost.com) and I have a php script designed to receive the data, in a post request. The code I am currently using, which gets the HOST of 000webhost, which is not what I want, I want to use the url (SomeName.000webhostapp.com) but it is redirecting to the host. 
Here is the code:

```
SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)gethostbyname("SomeName.000webhost.com")->h_addr);
```

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: If you are connecting to a `php` script then most likely it is behind a `HTTP` web server so you need to talk `HTTP` protocol. The socket doesn't care about `URL`s it just deals with connecting to the *host*. The rest of the `URL` is provided as part of the `HTTP` protocol after the socket has connected.

Comment: I know that, but it is **BEFORE** the url. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Sockets don't connect to a URL, they connect to a host and port.  The rest of the URL (i.e. the path part) is something you send *through* the socket, in an HTTP request, after you've connected.

It sounds like you're saying that you're trying to look up "SomeName.000webhostapp.com", but you're getting the IP address of "000webhost.com".  That's not surprising.  It's likely that your provider is using [name-based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based), where all the subdomains are actually handled by a single server on a single IP address.

When you send your HTTP request, you need to include a `Host: SomeName.000webhostapp.com` header, as required by the HTTP 1.1 protocol.  Based on that header, the server knows which site to respond with.